# Extract code from certain directories into a separate bundle in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have the following setup. 
I have a bunch of entry points (all with their own html page).
All entries are located in `/src/entry/`.
External code is located in `/node_modules`.
And I have a bunch of internal code that is used by the entries as well. This is located in `/src/node_modules/` in my case.

Now for optimal long term caching, I want to put everything from `/node_modules` in its own bundle called `vendors` and everything from `src/node_modules` in a bundle called `libs`.

How could I set this up using the SplitChunksPlugin?

I tried the following:

```
const optimization = {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: "vendors",
        chunks: "all"
      },
      lib: {
        test: /[\\/]src[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: "libs",
        chunks: "all"
      }
    }
  },
  runtimeChunk: "single"
};
```

But it puts everything in the vendors bundle.

---

Answer (score 0):

The `vendor` chunk's `test` regex is finding both folders since the name `node_modules` is used twice - once for what NPM installs, and once for libraries you are using in your source code.

If you can rename `/src/node_modules/` to `/src/lib/` and update your `vendor` chunk regex, you can split it out this way.

You could also change your `vendor` regex test to exclude the `/src` folder for matches if folder renaming isn't practical.